# GCP AI Platform doesn't list Kubeflow pipeline application on Pipelines page

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines

I am doing a lab titled as "TFX on Cloud AI Platform Pipelines" from Qwiklabs Machine Learning path. The instructions asks me to run a shell file by which I grant access to corresponding accounts and create a notebook instance and delete an existing instance.
The next instruction is creating an Kubeflow Pipeline through AI Platform console. I follow the instructions and everything seems in order. First a cluster is created on Kubernetes Engine then a Kubeflow Pipeline is created but the problem is AI Platform doesn't list that Kubeflow Pipeline so I can't access the Kubeflow Dashboard although the pipeline is there and healthy with a green tick. Does anyone have any idea?

[AI Platform Pipelines Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fb02X.png)

[Kubeflow Pipeline on Kubernetes Cluster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVWks.png)

I created the cluster and then the pipeline and I was expecting the pipeline get listed on AI Platform but it didn't.

Comment: Did you check if the pipeline is listed in Vertex AI instead of AI Platform ?

Comment: Yes I did but Vertex AI has a different infrastructure. Kubeflow Pipelines is provided as a separate service.